# What is the security impact to using a port different from 443 for HTTPS in my router

Tags: tls, router, ports

Are there any advantages or disadvantages for the security when using a non-standard port (i.e. not 443) for HTTPS in my router?

Comment: I've reduced your question so that it asks only about the security aspect - anything else is off-topic here. But the question is not fully clear to me: are you asking about changing the port for the router administration, about exposing some internal server with port forwarding or something else?

Comment: Given the remarkably small number of available ports, any open port will be found in very little time, so It's a poor attempt at security by obscurity.  Generally the only *good* reason to use a non-standard port is because you've got another process already listening on the standard port.

Comment: Yes, I thought about changing the standard TCP-Port for my router in mind with the idea of security by obscurity. But if there are existing such tools like @tjd mentioned, than I will don't touch it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been various attacks in this past (such as [this one from 2014](https://www.csoonline.com/article/2602181/attack-hijacks-dns-settings-on-home-routers-in-brazil.html) that modified the DNS servers on SOHO routers to malicious ones, and used that to target the users.

The attacks essentially worked by putting a JavaScript payload on a malicious (or compromised site), which made a XHR request to login to the router and change the DNS settings.

In order for this kind of attack to succeed, there there were quite a few requirements:

- The victim had to browse to a compromised site.
- The router had to be on an IP address the attacker could guess.
- The web interface had to be enabled on a port the attacker could guess.
- The router had to have the default password set.
- The router had to be vulnerable to CSRF.

So in theory, changing the default port could have protected you against this attack. An attacker *could* try connecting to all the ports (blindly) until they find the correct one, but that would make the attack ~65,000 times slower.

*But* there are much better ways to defend against this (such as changing the default password, or using a router that's not vulnerable to CSRF). So any security gain from changing the port is pretty minimal, compared to the other things that you should be doing to secure your router.

There's no real *security* downside to changing the port (although it might make your life harder for an administrative perspective). But there's barely any security benefits either.